# Use WKWebView in a UICollectionView cell

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, wkwebview

I use swift 3 and Alamofire to download pdf files. I would like to show the files in a UICollectionView with WKWebView but I cant figure out how. It’s no problem to show just one pdf file at a time but not in the collectionview. For example can’t I add the WKWebView to the cell.

I can do it with a UIWebView but then I have problems to show images. It’s mostly pdf files but it would be great to even support images which WKWebView can view.

So, is it possible to use WKWebView in each cell in a UICollectionView? Or is there any other way to show downloaded pdf:s (and sometime images)?

Comment: Hi... I want same functionality like display WKWebview in UICollectionviewcell. Here I want to show html content. But if more cells loaded app gets crashed. Did you get any solution?